# Exclude Group from Regex before export

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to exclude a group `(class=".*?")` from the whole Test String, maybe called a reverse match?

I have tried with negative Groups `(?:class=".*?")`, `(?!class=".*?")` and with the `.*(?:class=".*?")` but id didnt work for me.

How can i select the whole Test String but ignore the Group?

Test String:

```html
<table class="color sort">
  <tr>
    <td>Level 1</td>
    <td>Level 2</td>
    <td class="red">Level 3</td>
    <td>Level 4</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `preg_replace(".*(class=".*").*", "")`

this will remove all lines with a 'class="."' in them. If you just want the class text itself removed, just replace capture group 1 instead of the entire match. In general, non-matches can be done by matching what you don't want and replacing it with `""`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2X8mO/2/)

Comment: Thx for your answer. Ok i got it, but is there also a possibility when I hit the export Button on your demo Link, that it will export the whole HTML-Table without the Group?

Comment: so you just want the text that says class="something" removed or the whole line?

Comment: I need the whole Data (HTML-Table) without the `class="something"` :) In PHP it works with the preg_replace like a charm but im also interested to do this with your demo. Do i need to replace the group with nothing?

Comment: Yes, just replace group 1 with nothing rather than the entire match

Comment: I got something, but im not happy with it. Why? I just pasted in something

https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/1

Comment: [This should be what you're looking for](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/2)